# Operating system wasn't found (Live boot)

Tags: 12.04, boot, system

Using USB to ISO, I put Ubuntu 12.04 i386 on my USB and then connected it to another machine. On the machine, when I select boot from USB, it gives me the error, "An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving the Ubuntu ISO file into your USB key is just like saving any file. That is why you get that error.

You rather need to [create a bootable USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) key so that you ca install Ubuntu 12.04 and avoid that essage error.

Comment: I tried that and it worked on one of the machines, but on the one I'm trying to install ubuntu, my BIOS stops at "Verifying DMI Pool Data..."

Comment: What you may have done there (which I've accidentally done before) is when you installed Ubuntu on the first machine, is install the mbr onto the USB ... Which basically means you have to reformat the USB (Or delete the mbr from the usb)

Comment: You can test this by trying to boot your first machine without the sub inserted ...

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [UNetBootIn](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - it works fine too. The download link for Windows / Max/ Linux and usage process are available in the same link.

Make sure that USB is clean and formatted as FAT32 if you are making it bootable via Windows.